Gravitatis vs gravitas in Newton's Principia
I searched Newton’s Principia in Latin for “gravitatis” (gravitation) (occurs 161 times) and “gravitas” (gravity) (occurs 70 times). Did Newton use these two words interchangeably? I know gravity is more related to what we would call “weight” today. And after Einstein “gravitation” acquired other meanings as well. How would I think about Newton’s distinction of gravity and gravitation?

Isn't gravitatis just the genitive form of gravitas in Latin?

Thanks. This seems true. So Newton does not use a word we write as "gravitation" today? He only uses gravitas to mean weight.

English words ending with -tion generally correspond to Latin words ending with -tio (genitive -tionis), so I would expect gravitatio/gravitationis to be Latin for gravitation

It's at the very least unrealistic to try to 'dumb down' Newton by judging his work on single words. Sometimes phrases in Principia indicating gravitational attraction need not include the word gravity at all. For example "vis acceleratrix in solem" for the gravitational attraction of the sun.

@terry-s In the Editor’s Preface to the Second Edition there is this phrase “gravitatis actionem”. Cohen translates this as “the action of gravity”. So I see that, as commented above, gravitatis is merely the genitive of gravitas, it is not a different word with a different meaning. I have no intention to dumb down Principia. If gravitatis is the genitive of gravitas then gravitas is not a different word with a different meaning.

The dumbing down is in the implied assumption that Newton must always use a word grammatically close to 'gravity' when he wants to refer to gravitational effects. I already offered an example showing how that is not so.
